# Member defined more than once error message?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using c# in vs2010, and learning oop; my first attempt at declaring the object submission in my appCode folder keeps giving me the error message that

```
this member defined more than once
ambiguity between Submission.SubmissionId and Submission.SubmissionId
```

This error throws on each variable (CustId, BroId, Coverage). I followed a model I found in a tutorial for the syntax; is that the issue? Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class Submission 
    {
        int SubmissionId;
        int CustId;
        int BroId;
        int Coverage;
        //Array Product[] products;

        public Submission() {}
        public int SubmissionId 
        {
            get { return SubmissionId; }
            set { SubmissionId = value; }
        }
        public int CustId
        {
            get { return CustId; }
            set { CustId = value; }
        }
        public int BroId
        {
            get { return BroId; }
            set { BroId = value; }
        }
        public int Coverage
        {
            get { return Coverage; }
            set { Coverage = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are giving the same name to the variable and the property.

You can fix it by giving them different names:

```
public class Submission 
{

    public Submission() {}

    private int submissionId;
    public int SubmissionId 
    { 
        get{ return this.submissionId; }
        set{ this.submissionId = value; }
    }

    private int custId ;
    public int CustId
    { 
        get{ return this.custId ; }
        set{ this.custId = value; }
    }

    private int broId ;
    public int BroId
    { 
        get{ return this.broId ; }
        set{ this.broId = value; }
    }

    private int coverage;
    public int Coverage
    { 
        get{ return this.coverage; }
        set{ this.coverage= value; }
    }


}
```

Read [How to best name fields and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241105/how-to-best-name-fields-and-properties).

---

Also, you can use [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) :

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented
>   properties make property-declaration
>   more concise when no additional logic
>   is required in the property accessors.
>   They also enable client code to create
>   objects.

Here we go:

```
public class Submission 
{

    public Submission() {}

    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }

    public int CustId { get; set; }

    public int BroId { get; set; }

    public int Coverage { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: That would explain it. I'm doing a sort of "fake it till you make it" training program, where I sometimes do stuff, then find out why it works. This would be one of those times. Thanks, @Akram, and everyone who answered.

Comment: @Brazos: Good luck in your journey dear.

Answer (score 3):

Either declare your properties like this:

```
private int _submissionId;
public int SubmissionId 
{
    get { return _submissionId; }
    set { _submissionId = value; }
}
```

or you can use [Auto-Implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) (C# 3.0 or later, which do the same thing but require less typing)

```
public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're giving your public and private members the same name. You can't do that.
You can decide to give all your private members a prefix, such as an underscore (_), as [suggested here](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices).

Also, if you're not doing anything special in your properties, @Akram Shahda's answer is a good suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Your private and public members name is same.

change your private menbers name as

```
 int _submissionId;
 int _custId;
 int _broId;
 int _coverage;
```

if you are using visual studio 2008 or later try

```
 public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
  public int CustId { get; set; }
  public int BroId { get; set; }
  public int Coverage { get; set; }
```

Comment: Prefix fields with uderscore or m_ is awful)

Answer (score 1):

You named field and property with the same name, that causes the error.
You whould rename field for example to submissionId.
By the way, there is no need to define a field at all in this case. Use this property syntax:

```
public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have a field and a property with the same name this is not allowed.

The standard backing store implementation would look like this.

```
private int _CustID;
public int CustId
{
     get { return _CustID; }
     set { _CustID= value; }
}
```

If you are just using Properties with no get or set logic take advantage of the automatic properties.

```
public int CustID {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya, any how in the code u have declared each of SubmissionId, CustId, BroId, Coverage twice right. Why is so? u can directly declare a property below. Remove the first declaration.